# How to get the java to read the text field of user and give out another variable based on user?

Tags: java

I have a text field where user can type only numbers and a label which shows the price based on the number typed in the text field.

I need Java to be able to read the number which is typed into text field and internally java will provide another variable based on the input given by user.

It is like a range scale where it can read the value type in and automatically gives the assigned value based on range.

```
 String tourist = touristnumf.getText();
 if(touristnumf.getText() > =10)
        {
           boolean tourbetweenonetoten = true;
        }
```

Comment: the number is based on the a range like 1 - 10 to give out another variable.

Comment: 1-25 Very bad 25- Bad like speed reader?

Comment: Didn't completely understand your question, but I think you want to `return tourbetweenonetoten`?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any better way to explain it but I want the system to like understand the value typed in and give a reading based on input. Like I typed 10 into textfield and it will give me a reply that due to user typing 10  this costs 56.

Comment: I suggest editing your question with some more code snippets (for eg. showing the class type for `touristnumf`) and an example showing the exact output you want.

Comment: "Not being proficient in programming" has nothing to do with clearly explaining what you want to see happen on the screen. Surely you must have something cohesive in mind? (I mean, not as in ".. and then *magic* happens and then some number appears"...) Do you want `input * price` where `input` is the number that your user types in and `price` is in a label next to the input field?

Comment: Well I don't have a class or code for this. So that's why I type that example out. Because I am not sure how to code it out. This is actually like a rating scale on a second thought.

Comment: @usr2564301 no, it is based on the number user put in and the system will gives another number based on user put in. I buy 10 item n type it in, and then the system will give me a price based on this number.

Comment: is it easier to understand now?

Comment: yes, easier....but what price?? (there are infinite possiblities ... {0, 1, "when it rains...", ...}) ..."easiest" proposal for you: (equally distributed) random variable (`= price`)!

Comment: like 10 ppl going to trip need pay $145

Comment: why not $160 ...or $0 ...or $10?  ...or when it rains... ;)

Comment: ummm its like group package so fixed price

Comment: You seem to be in solution-mode (I think it may need actionlistener) before you are able to explain what you want to happen. To make us able to understand what you want, it would help if you first present the idea as a user of the system. Example: "The system takes input from a user via the command line", or "The user takes input via command line prompt" or "The system takes input via a userInterface using graphics text boxes". "Then the system translates the input as <insert small table/list to show the mapping> and/or calculates ... and returns the value to the user ..."

Comment: Since you mentioned "text field", you may want to present the code you have for that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read a number (`userInput`) and provide a mapped variable value:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class StackOverflowTest {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Map<Integer,Integer> translateMap = new HashMap<>();
    translateMap.put(1,11);
    translateMap.put(2,23);
    translateMap.put(3,14);

    Integer userInput = 2;

    System.out.println("translated " + userInput 
                        + " into " + translateMap.get(userInput));

// prints: 
// translated 2 into 23
  }
}
```

Alternatively for range:

```
public class StackOverflowTest {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Integer userInput = 12;
    Integer translated;

    if (userInput > 20) {
      translated = 100;
    } else if (userInput > 10) {
      translated = 50;
    } else if (userInput > 0) {
      translated = 250;
    } else {
      translated = 10000; // replace with exception handling
    }

    System.out.println("translated " + userInput 
                        + " into " + translated);

// prints: 
// translated 12 into 50
  }
}
```

Example of the two combined:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class StackOverflowTest {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Map<Integer,Integer> translateMap = new HashMap<>();
    translateMap.put(0,250);
    translateMap.put(1,50);
    translateMap.put(2,100);
    translateMap.put(3,5);

    String userInput = "19";

    // Converting a string into an Integer
    Integer input = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    Integer translated;

    // works to replace below if statement only 
    // because ranges happens to be devided into 10's
    translated = translateMap.get(input/10); // automatic flooring of float to int.

/*
    if (input > 20) {
      translated = translateMap.get(2);
    } else if (input > 10) {
      translated = translateMap.get(1);
    } else if (input > 0) {
      translated = translateMap.get(0);
    } else {
      translated = 10000; // exception handling
    }
*/

    System.out.println("translated " + userInput 
                        + " into " + translated);

// prints: 
// translated 19 into 50
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a range like 1-10 very bad, then 11-25 bad. Its like a range scale.

Comment: @user2963724 Added a solution for range.

Comment: Thank you scratte! I will try to figure out how to convert string to integer before applying.

Comment: @user2963724 added another example and how to convert a String to Integer.